# Helper not rerun when property changes

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to have a helper output nutrient totals based on a list (array) of ingredients. Since I want to display the totals of one of many nutrients I need to somehow pass it a parameter that defines the nutrient in question. So I figured a helper would be the way to go, something like this:

```hbs
{{nutrient-total list "kcal"}}
```

The problem is that the helper is only rendered/run once. However, the `{{#each}}` helper is updated when a new item is pushed to the list so it seems to be possible. I think I am missing something here. Should helpers be run again if a parameter changes, or should I be trying something else?

The list looks like this:

```js
{
  ingredient: {
    name: 'Potato',
    group: 'Veggies',
    nutrients: [{
      name: 'kcal',
      nutritionalValue: 87
    }, {
      name: 'kJ',
      nutritionalValue: 42
    }]
  },
  weight: 42
}
```

---

**For future reference:**

The solution with a helper:

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/257eea5db4ba89f9ba5500a1279cf64d?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

The solution with a computed property

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/217b5ad72fcc85762d1a8c118d55da21?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list objects is plain objects but you deal with like ember object.

I mean you shouldn't use `get` for those.

```
list.forEach(item => {
    let weight = item.weight;

    item.ingredient.nutrients.forEach(nutrient => {
      if (nutrient.name === unit) {
        total += weight * nutrient.nutritionalValue;
      }
    });
  });
```

But if you want to work for all types, use `Ember.get` like this :

```
const {get} = Ember;
...
list.forEach(item => {
    let weight = get(item, 'weight');

    get(get(item, 'ingredient'), 'nutrients').forEach(nutrient => {
      if (get(nutrient, 'name') === unit) {
        total += weight * get(nutrient, 'nutritionalValue');
      }
    });
  });
```

**UPDATE**

The main reason that helper doesn't work is that the `list` property should be notified.

In action you need to call `this.notifyPropertyChange('list');` at the end.

Also to get rid of this you can create a [class based helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_class-based-helpers)

Comment: Yes, very true. The real application does hold model records, that's why this was left in.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tried your solution but still no updates.. [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/217b5ad72fcc85762d1a8c118d55da21?openFiles=helpers.nutrient-total.js%2C)

Comment: @M.Oranje Ah I've forgotten to mention you need call 'this.notifyPropertyChange('list');' in action

Answer (score 1):

Instead of helper you can very well use computed property,

```
total: Ember.computed('list.[]','unit', function() {
        let total = 0;

        list.forEach(item => {
            let weight = item.get('weight');

            item.ingredient.get('nutrients').forEach(nutrient => {
                if (nutrient.name === unit) {
                    total += weight * nutrient.nutritionalValue;
                }
            });
        });
        return total;
    })
```

Reason for not running the helper might be, we are not changing the reference of `list`

Comment: To confirm, you can update list with empty(ie., `this.set('list',[])` ) and push object after that, then you can find your helper called for every pushObject..

Comment: You are right, that works ([Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/217b5ad72fcc85762d1a8c118d55da21?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)) however I still don't understand why this can't be done with a helper... Any ideas?

Comment: We are not changing the reference of list array. I would say don't use helper for this case. You might be interested in, object  are frozen debug build for helper. related [blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/11/30/ember-2-10-released.html#toc_other-notable-changes) and related [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/14244)